# Sensitivity to noise in nonlinear parameter estimation

Tags: parameter-estimation

Consider the model:
$$
y(\theta) = \alpha + \beta \cdot \tan(\theta + \gamma) + noise
$$
where $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are parameters I want to estimate and the noise is normally distributed: $N(0,\sigma)$.
$\alpha$ and $\beta$ has the unit meters btw.
The input variable is in the range:
$$
-10\pi/180<=\theta<=10\pi/180
$$

Given a dataset consisting of N $(\theta_i,y_i)$ pairs I estimate the parameters by minimizing:
$$
S = \Sigma_{i=0}^N [\alpha + \beta \cdot \tan(\theta_i + \gamma) - y_i]^2
$$

I ran a Monte Carlo simulation with
$$
\alpha = 0.5
$$
$$
\beta  = 1.0
$$
$$
\gamma = 4.0 \pi/180 
$$
$$
\sigma = 0.0005
$$

The parameter estimates are nearly normally distributed:
[image]

Why are the estimates for $\beta$ much better than those for $\alpha$ and $\gamma$?

And why are the estimates for $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ strongly correlated?

Comment: You can look at the sensitivity of the optimal solution with respect to the noise term. Or, you can use a different cost function to minimize. This is a well-studied problem and lot of things can be found regarding that on the Internet.

Comment: Something to keep in mind, your estimators for $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ will be correlated.

Comment: @Aruralreader: yes you are correct the estimators for $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are strongly correlated. But how could you see that without performing any Monte Carlo simulation?

Comment: I doubt you’ll find a method that doesn’t involve computation.